# Why is "can I get" replacing "could I have"?

Tags: british-english

I noticed the other day when serving the public that when asking for something, people were saying "Can I get an xyz, please". The previous time I had such a job it was "Could I have an xyz", or "May I have..." if they were being very polite.

Does anyone know when this trend started and what caused it?

Comment: Pure speculation: The new phrasing was popularized by rap/hip-hop music. As in, "Can I get a 'what what'?!"

Comment: I knew someone who speculated that it's because the hard "g" and "t" of "get" are more assertive sounds than the softer "h" and "v" of "have". I like this theory.

Comment: When we pronounce *get*, particularly in this phrase, the /t/ is almost never pronounced with the "hard" [t] sound that you are thinking of.  It is nearly always pronounced as a tap [ɾ] or glottal stop [ʔ].

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Speak for yourself :) In British English it's much more likely to be pronounced as a "hard t" than in the US (though it's by no means universal there either).

Comment: I'm not at all sure than one is replacing the other though I have to allow that there are some uses that top others in frequency. Wouldn't a peek at corpus studies be a better way to determine these things than simple speculation? *The Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English* warns that native speakers have notoriously bad judgments about how their language works.

Comment: @Cinque: That's not old fashioned. That's an obstinate denial of reality.

Comment: Best to say "I would like ..."  Just FYI.  The WORST is "Let's do ..."

Comment: The deleted answers are fun to read and they actually confirm that the change is happening. Some people really do get hot under their collar though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know the question is tagged “British English”, but for some historical perspective in  American English, this kind of request, formulated as “Can I get”, is not exactly some new invention. Here is a passage from a [novel written in 1859](http://books.google.com/books?id=nJAoY15RE6oC&lpg=PA3&dq=%22Lizzy%20Glenn%22%20%22Can%20I%20get%20some%22&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> “Have you any work, sir?” was repeated in a still lower and more timid voice than that in which her request had at first been made.
>
> “Yes, we have,” was the gruff reply.
>
> “**Can I get** some?”

And here’s one from [a 1906 novel](http://books.google.com/books?id=TEQe--ikVNIC&lpg=PP1&dq=joe%20the%20hotel%20boy&pg=PA85#v=onepage&q=%22can%20I%20get%22&f=false):

> Then our hero entered the place. “**Can I get** a room here for the night?” he asked of the clerk behind the desk.

And here, from a 1938 *Time* magazine article:

> At one ticket counter a soft-voiced woman had the ear of a clerk. “**Can I get** two tickets to Boston?” she inquired. The clerk asked who the other passenger was.
>
> “He’s in a hearse outside,” the woman explained.

Comment: I tagged the question as British English because I suspected the habit had been imported from somewhere; your evidence suggests it is American in origin.

Answer (score 8):

As a British observer I can confirm this is an Americanism and is being taken up by young, non-discerning British people who are being influenced by American T.V.

In Britain 'get' has a similar meaning to 'fetch' so a customer in a shop asking 'can I get...' would be suggesting that they actually fetch the article from wherever it is which is surely the duty of the shopkeeper: the shopkeeper 'gets' the article so that the customer can 'have' it.

'Could I have...' is surely the correct way for a customer to request an article or service (at least in Britain).

Comment: It would be useful to see numbers that support a thesis that this is both an Americanism and that it's being taken up by non-discerning people. (Corpus searches? Breakdowns by social class or education level?)

Comment: In the US, "get" just means "obtain" with no implication of physically bringing something from somewhere. "Have" refers to the *state* of owning something, while "get" is the inchoative equivalent (so, "get" = "to *begin* to have/own"): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inchoative_aspect. So, "Can I get [X]" here doesn't suggest the customer wanting to pick the item out for themselves, only to *acquire* the item.

Answer (score 1):

Is the question about the difference between 'Can I ...' & 'Could I ...' and 'May I ...' & *Might I ...'?

I will not address the difference between *can* and *may* as this has been discussed in the comments on the question (they are now part of idiomatic English for better or worse).

*May* and *might* are known as **modal auxiliary verbs**. According to the *Oxford Guide to English Grammar*, 'with modal verbs, we express ideas such as actions being possible or necessary' (p. 78) and 'the modal verbs are *will*, *would*, *shall*, *should*, *can*, *could*, *may*, *might*, *must*, *need*, *ought to*, and *dare*' (p. 113). In most cases, modal auxiliary verbs do not have tenses, and *The Cambridge Guide to English Usage* asserts that 'May I have a cup of tea?' and 'Might I have a cup of tea?' are grammatically the same, with the second '[seeming] overanxious to let the other party determine your right to the simplest of drinks' (p. 340).

In short: 'Can I ...' & 'Could I ...' are part of idiomatic English, but I wouldn't recommend them. The difference between 'May I ...' & 'Might I ...' is not grammatical but stylistic. All things considered, it is probably better to use 'May I ...' rather than any of the other alternatives as it is definitely correct and does not show overanxiousness.

Comment: The question is actually asking about "get" vs. "have", not "can" vs. "may".

Comment: You're probably right. I didn't realise that, because he used 'Can ...' in the first and 'Could ...' in the second.

Comment: Would anybody ever say "May I get..."?!