# Can I use the phrase "Can I get x please" and have it considered 'proper' english?

Tags: british-english

I seem to say it quite a lot without really realising it. I know of course, it should probably be something along the lines of "May I have" - But is "Can I get" really that wrong?

Thanks

Comment: There's a related question [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2596/why-is-can-i-get-replacing-could-i-have).

Comment: I would say that "can I get" is an Americanism creeping into British usage. Very strictly speaking, yes, it is wrong: "can I" means "am I able to" - see my answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/118579/43980)