# Ending a declarative statement with a question mark?

Tags: questions, speech, question-mark, intonation

Recently, there was a debate as to when one can legitimately end a declarative statement with a question mark, like writing “I don’t know?” as an answer, and what that could possibly mean.

The dialogue ran something like this:

> **Question:**   “How is your friend?”
>
> **Answer:**       “I don’t know?”

Is this wrong in terms of usage?

Answer (score 4):

I assume OP is referring to...

> [**high rising terminal (HRT)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_rising_terminal) - also known as *moronic interrogative, uptalk, upspeak, rising inflection, unnecessary inflection,* or *high rising intonation (HRI)*. A feature of some accents of English where statements have a rising intonation pattern in the final syllable or syllables of the utterance.

It doesn't *really* indicate a question in the mind of the speaker (unless maybe it's a kind of generic *"How will you respond to what I just said?"*, or *"Is that okay with you?"*). The general principle in English is only *write* a question mark at the end of a *question*, which OP's example probably isn't.

I and many other people find it incredibly irritating, but you can't change how people speak. That Wikipedia link above says, *it is ridiculed in Britain as "Australian question intonation"*, but I think Americans also associate it with [Southern California Valley Girl speech](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=if5XbL2I1Ic).

Comment: As a SoCal native my first thought would be that this is a case of upspeak as well. But, depending on the context, I may alternatively read / hear “I don’t know?” as meaning “I [think] I don’t know [but maybe if I thought about it some more or you gave me more information I would change my mind]”.

As an aside: many sociolinguists consider upspeak to not be a submissive speech pattern, but essentially daring the listener to disagree.

Comment: I've only ever heard it referred to as the Australian Interrogative Ending, complete with capital letters. I suppose that might give it a gravitas it doesn't deserve; but it seems to have gained traction in the UK since *Neighbours* and *Home and Away* started (around twenty years ago).

Comment: @redjives: I think it kinda depends on the speaker, the context, and the audience whether it's reflective of submissiveness, bravado/bluster, or out-and-out aggression. I have a niece who often uses it in the first mode there, and a son who often uses in the last. It's not really "native" to either of them, but I don't think they're normally aware of when they're using it, so I guess for each in their different ways, it's just part of their available repertoire (I certainly haven't had much success persuading either of them to avoid it around me! :(

Comment: See, amongst other things, [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30855).

Comment: @tchrist: I *thought* it had been covered before, but I didn't find that. I guess it's a dup.

Comment: There's an interesting perspective on this issue at [Language Log](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002159.html).