# Questionable statements

Tags: question-mark

I have often wondered if there's any common view on using a question mark on a statement meant as a question, such as "*I assume you've watered the plants?*". Is it right/wrong/merely a written representation of something that sounds perfectly fine in spoken language? I personally lean towards the last.

Cris

Comment: The question has already been asked, [Ending a declarative statement with a question mark? {duplicate}](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121502/ending-a-declarative-statement-with-a-question-mark) and [Intention of rising pitches](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30855/intention-of-rising-pitches).

Comment: @Rathony: What Andrew said. The questions in your links are more about the *intonation*, rather than the punctuation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nope, the first question is explicitly asking "Ending a declarative statement with a ***question mark***" and your answer to that is about it too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the first question (I linked) should be a duplicate of ***Is the question mark misused in affirmative sentences?***, not ***Intention of rising pitches***.

Comment: @Rathony: My answer there was primarily addressing the "moronic interrogative" intonation (I only mentioned the punctuation mark in passing). In principle there are two different issues here, but it looks like we've got several questions that sorta straddle both.