# Asking questions without subject-verb inversion — a new trend?

Tags: speech, questions

I don't know what it is called but I have seen people using the sentence which is the answer of some question as question itself.
For example:

> You are going to play tennis?  (this isn't much common still not
> wrong)
>
> I am looking good?
>
> You will prefer tea or coffee?

Is it just a new trend or some old style of speaking?

Comment: It's a relatively *uncommon* way of speaking. Strictly speaking all your sentences are *statements*, not *questions*. I believe some non-native speakers are more likely than native speakers to overuse ***intonation*** to force a statement to be interpreted as a question. The last example in particular seems far more likely to be from a Chinese waitress speaking English than from an actual native speaker.

Comment: This is fairly commonly recognized as a recent innovation called 'uptalk'. Possible duplicate of [Intention of rising pitches](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30855/intention-of-rising-pitches)

Comment: @FumbleFingers its common in speaking but not in writing because people find it easy not to differentiate between the question and answer , just the tone of question and Yes/No answer would work ..Yeah i agree there is no strictness , just for the sake of ease .

Comment: Well, there's uptalk and then there's the more traditional intentionally saying a declaritive with question intonation where it is intended as a question. Uptalk is distinct, really more of making a doubt out of a declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a perfectly usual way of speaking, which I have used and heard used over the last seven decades.

The interrogative is effected by a change in voice pitch, which makes it clear that it is a question you are asking.

In written form the question mark is essential.

It can, if not used with care, be misinterpreted as a statement rather than a question. For this reason it is often important to ensure you have the listener's full attention when you speak, and to say it directly to them:

'You will see him tonight?'.

'Yes'.

'Good, then I will let him know'.

Comment: I haven't heard it commonly but yeah i found that its perfectly fine . in french its more common , saying `ça va ?` and reply would be the same . ! but in english more natural is to say "will you see him tonight ?" but 'You will see him tonight?' creates comfort zone for listener or reader if properly spoken or written . what you say ?

Comment: @Hima It is often used in response to surprise information. 'When I speak to him at 8 o'clock I'll see what he says'.  'Ah, so you'll see him tonight?'

Comment: Yes ! this is more common when you are almost sure about yes/No and just need someone to confirm..Thanks.