# "Left with an 'eight'" meaning of an expression found on a song (by Talk Talk)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning, lyrics, songs

**The question**: in their song: [Such a shame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7OEvo-GjUg) (video), [Talk Talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_Talk) (album It's my life, 1984, remember, old folks), with the voice of [Mark Hollis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Hollis_(musician)), sings ([full lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/such-a-shame-lyrics-talk-talk.html)):

> Such a shame to believe in escape;  'A life on every face',  but that's
> a change.  **Until I'm finally left with an '8'**;  Tell me to relax, I
> just stare.

What does **left with an '8'** number reference mean in that context?

Some other verses in the song play in the same field, apparently:

> Number me with rage
>
> Number me in haste
>
> The dice decide my fate

The meaning seems related to dice cast. A single standard 6-face die cannot yield 8, but other less standard polyhedral dice (8-, 12-, 20-face polyhedra, used in war-games and role-playing games) can:

[image: Wikipedia: polyhedral dice]

Since they are non-standard, I will assume two 6-face dice are cast. Probabilities for the [two dice cast](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Esusan/courses/s60/split/node65.html) is about 14 % for an eight.

Comment: You should link to the [lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/such-a-shame-lyrics-talk-talk.html), not the video.

Comment: (But, generally speaking, the interpretation of song lyrics is off-topic here, since so much slang is involved, and often word choice is strongly influenced/distorted by meter and rhyme.)

Comment: @Hot Licks Lyrics link added. `song` and `lyrics` are SE tags. Here '8' does not seem to rhyme, and sometimes lyrics provide insights to solid language.

Comment: Who knows? It's Off Topic interpretation of sing lyrics. Maybe the writer was someone who'd naturally say *She's a ten!* of a woman he found very attractive (but he's ended up paired off with only an eight). Maybe he's just complaining about living in a world where people keep "rating" each other *(number me with range ... number me in haste)*. Choose whatever works for you.

Comment: I don’t play craps but I wonder if it’s related the dice game.

Comment: @Jim I was a role-playing gamer. There were 8-, 12- and 20-sided dice (aside with 4 and 6, the five Platonic solids or  [regular 3D polyedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polyhedron)). Not so common though

Comment: the song is based on the subversive George Cockroft novel **“The Diceman”** [The book tells the story of a psychiatrist who through sheer boredom starts to use the roll of a dice to make life decisions.  Cockroft based the plot on his own real-life experiences as a psychology student (Hollis also studied child psychology in Sussex Uni) during which he based his actions/decisions on the cast of a dice.](https://dervswerve.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/this-eagerness-to-change-with-a-roll-of-the-dice-such-a-shame/)

Comment: If any one wants to post it as an answer, feel free. Thanks for the trip down memory lane :) If someone has read the book, maybe they can say what the number 8 on the dice meant. BTW The original pop video, in the blog, is not too bad despite it being from the 1980s era.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "not too bad despite it being from the 1980s"... ouch.

Comment: To the OP, just as a reminder,  you can post the answer yourself. And you're allowed to accept your post as the right answer.

Comment: Sorry, but a request for interpretation of song lyrics is off-topic here.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I started checking whether the expression can found in the book

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about interpretation of a passage rather than a word or idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lyrics are inspired by this story of a psychiatrist who bases his actions/decisions on the cast of a dice: [The Diceman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dice_Man), a novel published in 1971 by George Cockcroft (pen name Luke Rhinehart). [Mark Hollis, who also studied child psychology at university](http://www.revolvy.com/main/index.php?s=Mark%20Hollis%20(English%20musician)&item_type=topic), recalls a "scene when he’s in party for an hour undergoing about ten different personality changes and that idea seemed quite appropriate in terms of what we’re doing."  It can be self-referential as well, relating to  lyrics writing. According to M. Hollis, "I’ve just written ten times as many lyrics as I needed and thrown the dice on which ones go in". A possibility is that the "Finally left with an 8" is the  outcome of the dice, which led to the choice of these cryptic lyrics.

When one casts two dice, the most probable outcome is 7, with [probability 16.7%](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/math/dice.html). Eight, as well as six, is the second most probable outcome (about 14%). My (over-)interpretation is that everyone has a fate just slightly different from that of the average person, who does not exist, except in statistics and polls.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/167597/44619 (if someone goes nitpicking)

Comment: But realistically speaking, it's impossible to throw an 8 on a single die/dice. See *...on the cast of a dice...* there has to be two. Oh, the blog actually says "the roll of a dice" and "the cast of a dice".  I think I may have opened a can of worms.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A You can have an "eight" with those [non-standard dice shapes](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Dice_(typical_role_playing_game_dice).jpg)